# Android: Intent for images/png shows mp4 videos in list

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-image

I want to load images to my app and provide the user with an intent to show all the images available to him/her by using the intent.setType method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
intent.setType("image/png");
```

Still, mp4 videos come up in the list even though there is a separate type for videos ("video/mp4") which I don't use (ever).

Is there a way to explicitly prevent videos from being shown in the list? Or is my only bet to check afterwards that the user hasn't selected a video?

Comment: I've been having this same issue, if I find an answer I'll post it.  Kind of strange you can set it, but it doesn't follow it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add this to your intent.

```
i.setType("image/*");
```